# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError while converting response into json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am doing a task in which I have to fetch the data for 20,000 records from external API. for this I am using requests module in python below is my code

```
def getdata():
    datanotfound=[]
    """ fetching the values from database to pass in the url  """
    values = mongo.db.collection.find()
    for value in values:
        value = pro.get("name")
        """ adding the value parameter into the url and fetching the data  """
        r = requests.get('myurl'+ value)
        if r!= None:
            response = r.json()
            info = response.get(val1)
            if info != None:
                val2 = info.get("val2")
                val3 = info.get("val3")
                val4 = info.get("val4")
                val5 = info.get("val5")
                """ saving the response in mongodb  """
                mongo.db.collection.insert_one({
                    'name':val1,
                    "address":val2,
                    "length":val3,
                    "width":val4,
                    "data":val5,           
                    })
            else:
                """ sending the values for which response was None  """
                datanotfound.append(value)
    return jsonify({'datanotfound':datanotfound})
```

This runs fine for some number of records but after some times i am gettting following errors:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 5 (char 5)
```

how can i get rid of this error.

Comment: Please comment your code...

Comment: I have added the comments

Comment: I recommend using one-line comments (`#`) unless you absolutely need to use multi-liners.